# Trying to search a results table, getting error on related columns

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use a search string to search a bunch of columns in a table, but when I add the search criteria in my controller, the columns that contain related data (virtual) give me errors about "int does not contain definition for ToUpper which leads me to believe I'm searching the fk column rather than the human friendly related column. Any thoughts on how I can fix that? (Please be gentle, I'm new at this, and this is my first question here ;) )

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 fwiw.... Code snippet below

```
        var machines = db.Machines.Include(v => v.Location).Include(v => v.Technician).Include(v => v.MachineStatu).Include(v => v.MachineTransportStatu).Include(v => v.Municipality);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            machines = machines.Where(s => s.MachineBarcode.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.MachineStatus.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.MachineMake.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.MachineModel.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.MachineTransportStatus.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.Location.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.Municipality.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.Technician.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));

        }
```

Comment: Check the data types of the columns you are trying to search.  Sounds like one of them is an integer datatype.

Comment: I think that's symptomatic of my real problem. For example, in the machines table, column Location is an int that relates to the pk in another table (Location). When I run the query though, I'm not showing the int to the user, the user see's the human friendly name (hence the .include(v => v.Location). So how can I edit say the s.Location.ToUpper line to apply to the related column (varchar in the Location table), and not the int column in the Machines table

Comment: Seems a bit odd that you are using the same searchString for all those different columns.  You might want to redefine your query and split it up accordingly.

Comment: I'm not opposed to redefining the query and splitting it up with separate search boxes for each of the criterion, though I had figured it would be user friendly for them to have a single search box to search all the columns. But then the question remains how can they search the string in the related table (say Location.LocationName) rather than the int that it's looking for now (Machine.LocationID)

Comment: You would have to then do a lookup on the PK table for the string that you are searching for, grab the ID, then use that instead.

Comment: As another thought, if I changed my query from var machines = db.Machines.Include(v => v.Location).Include(v => v.Technician).Include(v => v.MachineStatu).Include(v => v.MachineTransportStatu).Include(v => v.Municipality); to a LINQ to Entities statement, might that resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

first of all welcome to stackoverflow :)

and as the error says, "int does not contain definition for ToUpper " i guess you are making a simple mistake and trying to call a function that actually belongs to string object not to integer object. so, just find that column and do not use ToUpper for that column.